# Removing fields from document properties bar on Excel sheet linked to SharePoint library

Tags: document-library, excel, document, properties

I have an Excel sheet which is linked to a library in SharePoint, which has a 'Document Properties - Server' section at the top. They fill out the Excel sheet, save it to the library, and the information they put in the fields in the document properties section is used to populate some of the fields in the library.

I want to remove one of the fields, but this site/system wasn't developed by me, and I've never come across this before, so I don't know how.

[image]

The field I want to remove is the 'Document Status' drop down on the right hand side.

Can anyone offer any guidance on this?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this was a lot simpler than I expected:

I activated content types for the site and set the Document Status column to 'Hidden' rather than 'Optional', and now the column can't be seen from the Excel.

Just thought I'd answer my own post for anyone who finds themselves in a similar situation and comes across this.